# Installshield skip custom action if an application is already installed

Tags: installshield-2015

I have created a basic MSI project which will install few applications on the machine. My first step is to copy few folders and files to the destination machine. Then I have created two custom actions to run the exe files. I would like to skip custom action if that particular application is already installed on the machine. Also while copying the folders and files, I would like to skip if the folder or file already exists on the machine. I tried using install conditions, condition builder, system search but i am unable to resolve it.

Please provide any ideas to resolve these issues. Your answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All this can be resolved by using System Search.Refer (http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/isxhelp22/helplibrary/NewLaunchCondition.htm)

1) To check if file exists select (File path, by searching folders),enter file name, select directory and assign depth depending on the directory mentioned.
Suppose A.txt is present inside \B\C folder and you are selecting B while searching then depth should be >=2. The property mentioned in this process will get set with the file path if file exists.

2) To check if folder exists select (Folder path, by searching in a specific folder), follow the above procedure and mention folder name instead of filename.

3) To check if application is installed you can check by following one the above processes and find application specific folders/files.
Lastly use the public properties as a condition for your custom actions and components. Suppose you are checking for a file and setting a property ASONFILEFOUND, just mention this in component/custom action condition and those wont run if file exists.
If you still face issues enable windows logging and view the log to check whether properties used in System Search are getting set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path 'AcroRead.msi' -Transform 'Settings.mst' -Parameters '/q /norestart' -SkipMSIAlreadyInstalledCheck

use this command. if you are using Powershell for installation.

This will skip the MSI file check.